# How to do an Equirectangular texture transformation in an Image Texture Node?

Tags: texturing, vector-mapping

To be clear I am not putting this into the World material. Instead I am projecting a 3d image from a locator onto the geo surrounding it. I have had success in lining everything up when using an Environment texture with the location set to the camera location. I split this environment image into multiple layers with alphas. The issue is the environment texture node doesn't give me the alpha to cut it out in the material so I've had to swap to the Image Texture. I can't get them both to match as there is no Equirectangular option for the Image Texture node.

[image: Material with Environment texture. Correct]
[image: Material with Image Texture. Not Correct]

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain what it is you're trying to achieve - it's not clear (to me, at least) what you're trying to do here. It should be a matter of just getting the maths right to produce the required transform.

Comment: I found a workaround that was more labor intensive but essentially I was trying to get the same texture mapping from an image texture as I had from an environment texture because the environment doesn't let you output an alpha.